# How to create a Regex pattern that returns digits after string - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a Pattern that returns me results as shows below 
given list :

```
Help # 7256
Help # 83930
ph  # 7222
this is a test example
Help # 029299
New # 92929
```

output :

```
Help # 7256 
Help # 83930 
Help # 029299
```

Anything that starts with Help following by # sign then followed by 3 , 4 , 5 digit value

I tried something like this

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(Help #) (^|\D)(\d{3, 4,5})($|\D)");
```

Can someone please help me with creating this patten ? (in C#)

Comment: You can just check the string starts with `Help`?

Comment: Try this `(Help #)\s+\d+`

Comment: fyi: Pick up RegEx Editor [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55c24bf1-2636-4f94-831d-28db8505ce00).  It makes developing regular expressions in Visual Studio rather less painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C#, try this:

```
var list = new string[] { 
    "Help", "Help # 7256", "Help # 83930", 
    "ph # 7222", "this is a test example", 
    "Help # 029299", "New # 92929",
    "Help # 7256 8945", "Help # 83930 8998 787989"
};

// bear in mind that the $ at the end matches only these strings
// if you want it to match something like Help # 1284 12841 0933 SUBJECT HERE"
// then remove the $ from the end of this pattern
const string pattern = @"^(Help)\s#\s(\d{3,6})\s?(\d{3,6})?\s?(\d{3,6})?$";

var regex = new Regex(pattern);
foreach (string s in list)
{
    if (regex.Match(s).Success)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
Console.WriteLine("Done.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Outputs:

```
Help # 7256
Help # 83930
Help # 029299
Help # 7256 8945
Help # 83930 8998 787989
```

Comment: how can I get this to display something which has : Help # 7256 8945 and Help # 83930 8998 787989 to give result for all values along with Help # instead of just first one

Comment: See updated code. If you have something after the string though, remove the $ from the end of the pattern. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
/^Help\s*#\s*(\d{3,5})/gm
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tV9tB6)

*I should add that this also matches `Help # 029299` like specified in the OP, even though it  contains 6 characters.*

If you **only** want to match 3 to 5 characters, this will do it:

```
/^Help\s*#\s*(\d{3,5})\b/gm
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yL4hM6)

**Note**: If you ONLY want to match "`Help[SPACE]#[SPACE]number`", then simply remove all the `\s*`'s.

Comment: @rs. That's on purpose. I've added a comment to my answer explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution, assuming that you want to get all lines that starts with `Help #` (regardless of what comes after it), and the format of the input file is consistent:

```
if (currentLine.StartsWith(@"Help #"))
{
    // Do something with the line
}
```

[String.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx) method reference.

If you want regex solution, here is the regex (in literal string):

```
@"^Help #\s+(\d+)"
```

This can be used with [Regex.Match(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx). You can pick up the number from the capturing group 1. This one will only match line that starts with `Help #` followed by any number of spaces, then at least 1 digit. Note that this regex is only OK to use if you are scanning your file line by line.

If you must limit it to 3-5 digits:

```
@"^Help #\s+(\d{3,5})"
```

Comment: That will match `Help # Me`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Of course, if the format is not consistent, then whatever. It is possible that the string is `Help # 32453 me` also. The OP is not really clear on the real purpose, and only show very simple example.

Comment: actually OP wrote *followed by 3 , 4 , 5 digit value* I think thats pretty clear :)